# "Tu pars de la date A a la date B, soit X temps" - "Soit" s'accorde-t-il avec le complément temporel ?

Tags: conjugaison, compléments

"Le stage débute le 26 mars et finit le 27 août **"soit"/"soient"** 22 semaines."

Quelle est la forme correcte de "soit" dans les phrases comme celles-ci, c'est à dire quand le complément représente plusieurs éléments d'une quantité dénombrable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quand le mot **"soit"** peut être remplacé par **"c'est à dire"**, ou bien **"à savoir"**, il reste invariable, peu importe le complément qui suit.

Exemple :

> Un kilomètre, soit mille mètres.

Comment: Merci beaucoup il me semblait bien que je n'avais jamais vu le pluriel !

Comment: @Turbolay le pluriel est généralement utilisé avec un autre sens, en mathématique par exemple pour présenter un exercice: "Soient les points A, B et C formant un triangle équilatéral [...]". Mais le sens est bien différent du "soit" de la question initiale :)